# How to disable JavaScript debugging in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nunit, javascript-debugger

Recently when debugging my NUnit tests, I get the following error every time I attach to the NUnit process:

```
Cannot debug some of the code in process nunit. See below for status.

Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code succeeded.
JavaScript code falied. Not implemented

Click OK to continue debugging the remaining code. To disable debugging the failed type(s) of code in the future, change the corresponding setting in the project properties dialog.
```

Can anyone tell me how to disable javascript debugging? I'm not trying to debug javascript, just managed code and this popup is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another trick is to not use IE but for instance Chrome or Firefox as your default browser.

Comment: I do use Chrome as my default browser. Like I said, I don't do any javascript debugging ever. I'm attaching to an NUnit process.